# MySQL WHERE-condition in procedure ignored

Tags: mysql, sql, select, procedure

I am trying to make a procedure with arguments. But when I use them in a `WHERE` condition it is like there were never there. They are simply ignored.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p //

CREATE PROCEDURE p (IN player TEXT, OUT num INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM `sg_playerstats` WHERE `player` = player; 
END

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Num gets filled correctly, but whatever I put in player, the result is ALWAYS 66. (The table has 66 rows!)

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rename your parameter,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p (IN _player TEXT, OUT num INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM `sg_playerstats` WHERE `player` = _player; 
END
```

the reason why you are getting that is because it happens to have name collision.

Comment: Oh! I would have never thought of that! Thank you!

Comment: You just save my day. Thanks