# Mysql Stored Procedure Ignores Parameters and WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have the following which works great:

```
SET @param = '%string%';

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE IF(@param IS NOT NULL, LIKE @param, TRUE);
```

However when I change to this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN param VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @param = param;

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE IF(@param IS NOT NULL, LIKE @param, TRUE);
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL test('%string%');
```

All rows are returned as if there were no parameter passed in.

I assume that there is some limitation or restriction with MySQL that I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL WHERE-condition in procedure ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515125/mysql-where-condition-in-procedure-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but please try this with prepared statement

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN param VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @param = param;

SET @q = CONCAT("SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE IF(",@param," IS NOT NULL, LIKE ",@param,", TRUE)");

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is syntactically wrong and won't get compiled:

```
WHERE IF(@param IS NOT NULL, LIKE @param, TRUE);
```

and you can't just place variable values like that to construct an SQL statement.
You need a Prepared Statement to prepare and execute such statements.

Try the following: (you need to replace `column_name` with valid column name from your table.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test //

CREATE PROCEDURE test( IN param VARCHAR( 255 ) )
BEGIN
  SET @param = param;

  SET @query = CONCAT( 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE column_name LIKE ' );
  SET @query = CONCAT( @query, ' IF( \'', @param, '\' IS NOT NULL, \'' );
  SET @query = CONCAT( @query, @param, '\', TRUE )' );

  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DROP PREPARE stmt;   -- deallocate prepare stmt;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;

CALL test('%string%');
```

If you run `select @query`, it will return following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
 WHERE column_name LIKE IF( '%string%' IS NOT NULL, '%string%', TRUE )
```